# Laptop shutting down after startup?

Tags: boot, laptop, battery

Few months ago, battery broke from my laptop and it worked only when charger is plugged. Now it shuts during startup. I press the power button, it starts to flicker some lights like usual, but then dies.

I have tried to unplug it and remove battery, but it doesn't work. Also, because it doesn't even get to turn the screen on or get keys before it breaks, I can't do anything software based.

Does someone have idea what's going on or do I have to give up?

Comment: buy a replacement battery?

Comment: Battery broke a while ago, but it worked when charger was plugged. I think that power supply might be busted.

Comment: That or the connection Adapter to Laptop is intermittent / faulty.

Comment: Some laptops will not work at all if the battery is fully dead or missing. Unsure why, but replacing the battery with one that works even a little bit fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen on Dell laptops when a capacitor had failed on the motherboard. The symptoms were exactly as you describe: when I pressed the power button the light would come on, but then after a few seconds it would just go off again. One of the laptops was still under warranty and Dell replaced the motherboard. The other one was fixed by an independent repair shop. In both cases after the repair the laptops worked normally for several more years.

You don't say what model your laptop is, and I don't know whether other makes of laptop are affected in the same way, but if this is the reason it would explain why disconnecting or connecting the battery makes no difference.

Comment: It's Asus laptop and I think that I should just get it repaired by professionals.

Comment: @AapoPesonen Yes, I think this is probably a job for a repair shop. The only thing you need to check is how much it will cost as the cost of  replacement motherboard and fitting may be more than the laptop is worth.